# How to do meta_query when the value of a meta_key is an array?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I am working on Wordpress website and hit an obstacle when I tried to do the following query:

```
    $args=array(
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'meta_query'    =>  array(
        array(
       'key'     => 'ad_info', 
        'value'  => // check again with weight between 50 and 100,
        'compare' => //compare operator, 
        ),      
       )
     );
```

the value of the key  `ad_info` is: `Array ( [weight] => 48 [height] => 160)`    and I want to check if the value of `weight` in this array is between 50 and 100.
Can anybody help me on this problem?
Thanks

Comment: It can't be done using a meta query - you need to rethink the way you're storing data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mysql array values saved as strings, and it make problem for WP_Query filtering.

So best solution in this problem - change saving method to 2 keys:

**ad_info_width** and **ad_info_height**.

In that way you can use meta_query between compare.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to do that because the theme has saved the value in that way. But maybe I don't have another choice rather than saving the data again in another format.